# Do Chazal discuss Mishael and Eltzaphan

Tags: historical-figures, parashat-shemini

Do chazal provide any information on מִישָׁאֵל and אֶלְצָפָן  the levite cousins of Aron and Moshe who removed Nadav and Avihu from the mishkan ([Vayikra 10:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0310.htm#4))? I'm looking for any sources that discuss any other parts of their lives.

Answer (score 4):

In [Bamidbar 3:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0403.htm#4), Elitzafan becomes Nassi over Kehos (which is why Korach went against Moshe).

Comment: I think the OP was asking for quotes from the gemarah or medrash ("chazal") as opposed to pesukim

Comment: @vulcandeathgrip I disagree. I think the OP didn't realize there were anymore relevant pesukim, but he would gladly take them among other teachings about their lives.

Comment: Quote: "I'm looking for any sources that discuss any other parts of their lives."

Comment: It appears, upon first glance, that this is effectively **all** that's written about Eliẓaphan (with no further mention of Misha'el) in all of Midrash Rabbah, Midrash Tanhuma, Yalqut Shim'oni, Sha"S and The Holy Zohar.

Comment: @Lee That sounds like useful information to put into an answer.

Comment: This point is mentioned in the first Midrash Tanchuma on Korach - https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Korach.1?vhe=Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet&lang=bi

Answer (score 0):

In [Sukkah 25b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.25b.1?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi), [Sifrei Bamidbar 68](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Bamidbar.68.1?vhe=Wikisource&lang=bi) ([and in other midrashim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%9F&tab=text&tpathFilters=Talmud%7CMidrash%2FAggadic%20Midrash%2FMidrash%20Rabbah%7CMidrash%2FAggadic%20Midrash%2FMidrash%20Aggadah%7CMidrash%2FAggadic%20Midrash%2FMidrash%20Tanchuma%7CMidrash%2FAggadic%20Midrash%2FMidrash%20Tanchuma%20Buber%7CMidrash%2FAggadic%20Midrash%2FOtzar%20Midrashim%7CMidrash%2FAggadic%20Midrash%2FYalkut%20Shimoni%20on%20Torah%7CMidrash%2FHalachic%20Midrash&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance)), it says that according to Rabbi Akiva, Mishael and Eltzaphan were the men who had impurity of the dead (for removing Nadav and Avihu) and thus couldn't make the Pesach ([Bamidbar 9:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Bamidbar.68.1?vhe=Wikisource&lang=bi&p2=Numbers.9.6&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0)), which led to instituting Pesach Sheni.