# How Were Princes of the Tribes Chosen?

Tags: politics-government, parshat-nasso, police-authorities, princes-of-tribes

In [Numbers 7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0407.htm), we are told about the special offerings the princes of the Tribes brought to the Tabernacle. This is not the only time we hear of this position. Princes are present in [Joshua 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0609.htm) also, for example.

**How were princes of the tribes chosen?** Was it hereditary or an election process. [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27345/4682) suggests it might have been put to a consensus of some sort.

Please source you answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set seemed to be the ones who were the taskmasters who took beatings in Egypt in order to protect the people.

[This](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/bonchek/archives/nasso66.htm) site discusses the Rashi which cites the medrash to this effect.